Rsync command to move directories and overwrite existing ones
I need an rsync command that moves directories from a source folder to a remote folder and overwrites existing directories on the remote side.

I don't want to write into existing directories on the remote side. So if a directory exists on source and remote, it should be deleted on the remote side and a new directory should be created to replace it.
If a directory doesn't exist on the source side, the remote one shouldn't be deleted (so no --delete)
If a directory doesn't exist on the remote side, it should be moved.

Edit: Here is an example file list before the operation has started:
.
├── remote
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── test1_old.txt
│   │   └── test2_old.txt
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── test1.txt
│   │   └── test2.txt
│   └── d
│       ├── test1.txt
│       └── test2.txt
└── source
    ├── a
    │   ├── test1.txt
    │   ├── test2.txt
    │   └── test3.txt
    ├── b
    │   ├── test1.txt
    │   └── test2.txt
    └── c
        ├── test1.txt
        └── test2.txt

And after the operation it should look like this:
.
├── remote
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── test1.txt
│   │   ├── test2.txt
│   │   └── test3.txt
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── test1.txt
│   │   └── test2.txt
│   ├── c
│   │   ├── test1.txt
│   │   └── test2.txt
│   └── d
│       ├── test1.txt
│       └── test2.txt
└── source
    ├── a
    │   ├── test1.txt
    │   ├── test2.txt
    │   └── test3.txt
    ├── b
    │   ├── test1.txt
    │   └── test2.txt
    └── c
        ├── test1.txt
        └── test2.txt


What do you mean by 'it should be moved'?

Edit the question and add a sample of the source and destination and what you expect to happen. Also include what you have tried and what isn't working. Is the same supposed to happen with subdirectories and files?

This will require a script, not just a command.  You need conditionals, for sure.

I added a tree output before and after the operation was performed. I hope this makes things a bit clearer. Notice that "d" on the remote side wasn't deleted, even though it doesn't exist on the source side. And the old content of "a" was replaced. Subdirectories are not relevant in my case.
With "it should be moved" i meant that the files should not be copied but moved to the remote side, but that is not very important. I can also delete them after the operation.
I have only used the KDE filemanager so far, since I couldn't find suitable rsync parameters.
